# Как поместить StackLayout в SwipeView? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, мобильная-разработка

Хочу реализовать открытие меню на главной странице свайпом влево используя **xamarin forms**. Меню и контент главной страницы - два `StackLayout` на весь экран.

Желаемый эффект - аналогично открытию директа instagramm при свайпе вправо. Каким способом это можно реализовать?

Если есть пример кода буду весьма благодарен.

Answer (score -1):

[`CarouselPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page) - используйте это, подойдет для большинства задач.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ссылка на офф. документацию в данном контексте допустима.